# ModelBindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(key) always returns null

Tags: json, angular, asp.net-mvc-5, model-binding

I'm using AngularJS to manipulate a fairly complex parent object with children that need to behave quite differently server-side. Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25187178/671817), which appears pretty solid, I've created the test case below. The issue I'm running into is that whenever I enter the `CreateModel` function, any call to `bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(key)` returns null. I've checked all values in the debugger. The object type appears to be loaded, but no values have yet been bound.

My Models:

```cs
public class Menagerie
{
    public Menagerie()
    {
        Critters = new List<Creature>();
    }

    public string MakeNoise()
    {
        return String.Join(" ", Critters.Select(c => c.MakeNoise()));
    }

    public List<Creature> Critters { get; set; }
}

public class Tiger : Creature
{
    public Tiger() { }
    public override CreatureType Type => CreatureType.Tiger;
    public override string Sound => "ROAR";
}

public class Kitty : Creature
{
    public Kitty() { }
    public override CreatureType Type => CreatureType.Kitty;
    public override string Sound => "meow";
}

public class Creature
{
    public Creature() { }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual CreatureType Type { get; set; }
    public virtual string Sound { get; }
    public string MakeNoise()
    {
        return $"{Name} says {Sound ?? "nothing"}.";
    }

    public static Type SelectFor(CreatureType type)
    {
        switch (type)
        {
            case CreatureType.Tiger:
                return typeof(Tiger);
            case CreatureType.Kitty:
                return typeof(Kitty);
            default:
                throw new Exception();
        }
    }
}

public enum CreatureType
{
    Tiger,
    Kitty,
}

public class CreatureModelBinder : DefaultModelBinder
{
    protected override object CreateModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext, Type modelType)
    {
        CreatureType creatureType = GetValue<CreatureType>(bindingContext, "Type");
        Type model = Creature.SelectFor(creatureType);
        Creature instance = (Creature)base.CreateModel(controllerContext, bindingContext, model);
        bindingContext.ModelMetadata = ModelMetadataProviders.Current.GetMetadataForType(() => instance, model);
        return instance;
    }

    private T GetValue<T>(ModelBindingContext bindingContext, string key)
    {
        ValueProviderResult valueResult = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(key); // valueResult is null
        bindingContext.ModelState.SetModelValue(key, valueResult);
        return (T)valueResult.ConvertTo(typeof(T)); // NullReferenceException
    }
}
```

My script:

```js
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('app', []).controller('CritterController', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {

        $http.post('/a/admin/get-menagerie', { }).success(function (data) {
            $scope.menagerie = data.menagerie;
        });

        $scope.makeNoise = function () {
            $http.post('/a/admin/make-noise', { menagerie: $scope.menagerie }).success(function (data) {
                $scope.message = data.message;
            });
        }
    }]);

})();
```

**Things I've tried**

I've tried just using a string to indicate the class name, as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6485552/671817) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7222639/671817). However, the call to `bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(key)` still returns null, resulting in a `NullReferenceException`.

I also checked to ensure the model is binding properly. When I change my `CreatureModelBinder` to the following, everything maps fine. But each creature loses its inherited type and becomes a `Creature`.

```cs
public class CreatureModelBinder : DefaultModelBinder
{
    protected override object CreateModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext, Type modelType)
    {
        return base.CreateModel(controllerContext, bindingContext, modelType);
    }
} // MakeNoise returns: "Shere Khan says nothing. Mr. Boots says nothing. Dr. Evil says nothing."
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The solution I was hoping existed:**

When posting JSON data, it appears that all keys have the model name prepended. This can be solved simply by changing the first line of `CreateModel` to:

```
CreatureType creatureType = GetValue<CreatureType>(bindingContext, bindingContext.ModelName + ".Type");
```

**Previous Answer:**

The data my AngularJS function posts is labeled by Chrome as "Request Payload", which cannot (as far as I can tell) be accessed in `CreateModel`. When I implemented @DarinDimitrov's solutions line-for-line, the data was posted as "Form Data", which was available in `CreateModel`. I found a little more info about the difference between data types [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23118249/whats-the-difference-between-request-payload-vs-form-data-as-seen-in-chrome), though AngularJS doesn't appear to be able to send data with a content-type other than application/json without some fancy acrobatics.

I did, however, find that I can access an instance of my object (and create a new instance with a different type) in the `BindModel` function as follows:

```
public class CreatureModelBinder : DefaultModelBinder
{
    public override object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        Creature instance = (Creature)base.BindModel(controllerContext, bindingContext);
        Creature newInstance = (Creature)Activator.CreateInstance(Creature.SelectFor((instance).Type));
        newInstance.Name = instance.Name;

        return newInstance;
    }
} // MakeNoise() returns: "Shere Khan says ROAR. Mr. Boots says meow. Dr. Evil says meow."
```

The greatest downside I can see is that every property in the object must be manually mapped to the new instance, which can become cumbersome and produce hard-to-track bugs.

This is what I'm using for now, though I'm open to suggestions if anyone can provide a more elegant solution.

**EDIT**

I found that when posting as application/json, the model data can be accessed using this: